# Calculate Count of data with join and 'where' clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with columns `[Dist_Id]`, `[Name]`, `[FatherContactNumber]`.

Now I need the count of all children in a district and the count of children with `FatherContactNumber != ''`.

I have created the query to find all children where `FatherContactNumber != ''`, but I also need total number of children.

```
select 
    d.Dist_Name, count(*) [Total_Childernd] 
from 
    Children c
inner join 
    District d on c.Dist_Id = d.Dist_Id
where 
    c.FatherContactNumber != ''
group by 
    d.Dist_Name
```

Output:

```
    Dist_Name        Total_Childernd_With_Numbers
-------------------------------------------
    Dist_Name1       313
    Dist_Name2       215
    Dist_Name3       1624
    Dist_Name4       38
    Dist_Name5       2874
    Dist_Name6       118
    Dist_Name7       72
    Dist_Name8       3590
```

My desired output is

```
  Dist_Name     Total_Childernd_With_Parent_Numbers       Total_Childernd
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Dist_Name1    |   313                             |
    Dist_Name2    |   215                             |
    Dist_Name3    |   1624                            |
    Dist_Name4    |   38                              |
    Dist_Name5    |   2874                            |
    Dist_Name6    |   118                             |
    Dist_Name7    |   72                              |
    Dist_Name8    |   3590                            |
```

I don't need to to create a nested query.

Please suggest the best way to do this because I have billions of records.

Comment: can you be more specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How this query,

```
select d.Dist_Name
        ,count(*) [Total_Childernd] 
        ,count(case when c.FatherContactNumber !='' then 1 else null end) as [Total_Childernd_With_Numbers]
from Children c
inner join District d on c.Dist_Id=d.Dist_Id
group by d.Dist_Name
```